# ST_ConcaveHull produces "No function matches given name" in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, concave-hull

I'm using Postgis 2.2.2. This is my table:

```
county       | character varying       |
wkb_geometry | geometry(Polygon,27700) |
```

I want to get the area of the concave hull around all polygons in a particular county.

This is what I'm trying:

```
select st_area(st_concavehull(st_multi(st_collect(wkb_geometry)))) 
from mytable where county='XX';
```

But I'm getting:

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I think the problem is with `st_concavehull`. I've also tried just `st_concavehull(wkb_geometry)`, but that produces the same error message.

What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ST_ConcaveHull takes an argument.  You might be looking for ST_ConvexHull.
To use ST_ConcaveHull, you need to pass in a shrink factor.

Try

```
SELECT st_area(st_concavehull(st_multi(st_collect(wkb_geometry)),0.8)) 
FROM mytable WHERE county='XX';
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! To simplify things, can I just do `SELECT st_area(st_concavehull(wkb_geometry,0.8)) FROM mytable WHERE county='XX'` (which also runs without errors) or will that produce odd results?

Comment: You only need ST_Collect if you have more than one geometry and want the concave hull of the whole set rather than just 1 row.  ST_multi I would get rid for sure.